# What is the missing number in the figure?

Tags: riddle, mathematics, logical-deduction

I have no idea what is, no logic ... but probably I am missing something
[image: Puzzle]

Comment: Ha! A Bulgarian puzzle?!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you please [specify](/help/referencing) where you found this puzzle?

Comment: Is there an english translation for the instructions given above?

Comment: used google translate:   `Specify the missing number in the figure:`

Answer (score 17):

I think the answer is

> B. 37

The pattern is

> start from 1 then rotate clockwise two steps,
>  so you'll have sequence {1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, X} then you'll see the pattern:
>  1 (+1) 2 (+3) 5 (+5) 10 (+7) 17 (+9) 26 (+11) **37**

Comment: so the next one after 37 will be 50