# Which figure is not needed in the pattern?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

I have been trying to figure it out, but no logic so far.

[image: Figure]

This question was given to me by the University of Sofia.

Comment: [Again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68404/what-is-the-missing-number-in-the-figure#comment205567_68404), could you please [specify](/help/referencing) where you found this puzzle? Otherwise, it might be put [on hold](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/new-off-topic-reason-for-puzzles-where-the-source-is-not-mentioned?cb=1).

Comment: question given in the university of sofia

Comment: Did you really mean to write "not needed"? At least 2 out of 3 respondents have treated this as a "which of these is not like the others" puzzle. But if the puzzle is actually to identify an unneeded clue, the odd man out can't be the answer.

Comment: It is probably the first one, because it has a circle that doesn't look quite the same as the others. I did not write this comment in Rot13 because, in my opinion, this was quite obvious... unless there is a catch!

Answer (score 1):

Ans is

> a

because

> the inner circle in the pattern is not touching both the other circles while in the rest of the three diagrams both the circles are touching the inner circle ..

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> the first shape.

Because

[image]

> moves counterclockwise

[image]

> this moves repeatly between West and South only

[image] and [image]

> stay together next to each other, decide where to stay after the other two shapes move, and circular shapes always stay before the other one.

Answer (score 0):

it is

> the first one

because

> the small circle on the left is not touching any other circles

Answer (score 0):

last one,

it is not same rhythm with first 3,
 would like this
[image]